# How to get the total number of nested files and folders inside the main folders inside a document library

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp-powershell

We have a SharePoint online document library which contain 40 folders on the root. now i want to count how many nested sub-folders and files each of the 40 folders contain? now in SharePoint the built-in "File Size" column will show how many direct folders and files exists and not the nested number of files and folders.

[image]

so can i write a power shell script or other approaches to get the total number of nested sub-folders and files?

Comment: https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/05/sharepoint-online-get-files-sub-folders-count-in-document-library-using-powershell.html

Comment: @Christoffer this approach does not show the total number of all files and folders recursively

Comment: The script has everything you asked for, you just need to make some small changes to sum up the totals.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [SharePoint REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-to-know-the-sharepoint-rest-service?tabs=csom) to get the number of items with the property `ItemCount`

Sample of a REST:

```
https://your-tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/your-site/_api/Web/Lists/GetByTitle('your-list')/Items?$select=FileRef,Folder/ItemCount&$expand=Folder
```

Meaning:

- you must expand `Folder`
- you must select `Folder/ItemCount`

Answer (score 0):

There are two methos to get count of sub-folders and files in each folder.

1.When a document library has multiple folders, sub-folder and files, you could get the number of sub-folders and files at each level by adding "Folder Child Count" and "Item Child Count" columns to the view.

Click Show or hide columns -> Select "Folder Child Count" and "Item Child Count" columns.

For example: A document library has a root folder testA, in the root folder testA has a sub folder 1 and test file, in the sub folder 1 has a sub folder 1-1.

[image]

2.Use PnP PowerShell to get count.

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/emilytestnew"
$ListName = "0126"
$CSVFile = "C:\Folders.csv"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -Interactive
  
#Get the list
$List = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName
 
#Get Folders from the Library - with progress bar
$global:counter = 0
$FolderItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500 -Fields FileLeafRef -ScriptBlock { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress -PercentComplete `
            ($global:Counter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Getting Items from List:" -Status "Processing Items $global:Counter to $($List.ItemCount)";}  | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder"}
Write-Progress -Activity "Completed Retrieving Folders from List $ListName" -Completed
 
$FolderStats = @()
#Get Files and Subfolders count on each folder in the library
ForEach($FolderItem in $FolderItems)
{
    #Get Files and Folders of the Folder
    Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $FolderItem.Folder -Property Files, Folders | Out-Null
     
    #Collect data
    $Data = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
        FolderName     = $FolderItem.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
        URL            = $FolderItem.FieldValues.FileRef
        FilesCount     = $FolderItem.Folder.Files.Count
        SubFolderCount = $FolderItem.Folder.Folders.Count
    }
    $Data
    $FolderStats+= $Data
}
#Export the data to CSV
$FolderStats | Export-Csv -Path $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Result:

[image]